# Stream video php

Tags: php

I am trying to get my php video handler file to serve up videos and am testing it on the file handler page itself without luck.

**Weird behaviour:** A window just pops up asking me if I want to download the file, even if I delete the readfile(). If I change video/x-flv to video/flv then a player loads in my window but the file does not play. Also if I take away that header all together my browser crashes.

I figured this script should place the video in the browser at the least and have it be playable in the browser if I am testing the file directly with the browser. The file path is correct after the query... Also the file is outside of my web directory but I don't think that should matter because I can serve images outside the directory successfully using a similar script. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$sql="SELECT file_name FROM video WHERE vid_id=?";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute(array($ID));

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$file_name = $row['file_name'].".flv";
}

$path="/home/g/Desktop/processed/".$file_name."";


//check if image is readible and type
if (is_readable($path)) {
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
header("Expires: -1");
header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');

$content=readfile($path);


}
else {
error_log("Can't serve video: $file_name");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming doesn't work like that.
To have a proper streaming you need to use a Player like: http://flowplayer.org/

If you just send the content of the video, the browser will pop up the save dialog

Comment: Ok well I have a player, this file is the handler, I was just testing it directly and thought the popup was abnormal. I want to serve the file with the player with the src being video_handler.php?ID=$vid_id. The stream is not coming through for some reason which is why I thought something was wrong.

Comment: @scarface it can't work like that, you need to give the player his standard url so apache can manage the accept-range header. Otherwise you will need to parse the request header within your script, but at that point stuff gets harder. Anyway if this answer helped you think to +1 it. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by parsing the request header? And don't worry about your votes lol, I will upvote everything you've written once I solve this. And if it does not work how come it works for an mp3 player?

Comment: maybe because your mp3 players works differently than your video player. Regarding accept-range headers are: http://www.http-stats.com/header/Accept-Ranges they are used to easly move at the specified time by the user

Comment: Did you downvote me because I didn't upvote you yet lol? I am still trying to figure this out just hold on.

Comment: It turned out I was using OS player and that player did not even work. I changed to flow player and now it is working. Here take your votes even though you down-voted me you bum.

Comment: too bad +1 on comments deosn't give rep :)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use php to pass videos to OS player. I switched to flow player and things are working.